# Making a GUI with Tkinter

Tags: python, list, user-interface, tkinter, row

When I run the following code:

```
from tkinter import *

rows = []
for i in range(3):
    cols = []
    for j in range(3):
        e = Entry(relief=RIDGE)
        e.grid(row=i, column=j, sticky=NSEW)
        e.insert(END, '%d.%d' % (i, j))
        cols.append(e)
    rows.append(cols)

def onPress():
    for row in rows:
        for col in row:
            col.get(),
        print()

Button(text='Calculate', command=onPress).grid()
mainloop()
```

I get a 3 by 3 grid where I can enter six numbers. I want to incorporate the following code into the above code:

```
x = r_1[0] + r_2[0] - r_3[0]

y = r_1[1] + r_2[1] - r_3[1]

z = r_1[2] + r_2[2] - r_3[2]


num = x + y - z

list = [x, y, z]

i = 0
while (i < 3):
    
    fin = 2000*list[i]*num

    print(fin)
    i = i + 1
```

Such that when I run the code I get an output of three numbers displayed below the "Calculate" button in the grid. The r_1[0] denotes the first entry in the first row of the grid, the r_2[0] denotes the second entry in the first row of the grid etc.

I'm not sure how to make the code work.

Comment: I can't get second snippet working.

Comment: That's part of my question, how do I code the second snippet in such a way that in works together with the first snippet to produce the desired result. Thanks.

Comment: I basically just wanna create a GUI for the code in the second snippet.

Comment: This It's not an answer but I want just you to know that the old widget UI is outdated now, the future is using web technologies in the UI, so, instead of solving this issue maybe it's time to completely change the lib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You could try something like below:**

```
# Change our import statement to import the tkinter module as tk
import tkinter as tk

# Define our function for the action to complete on our button press
def onPress(rootInstance, output):
    # Get our input values as a dictionary
    inputVals = rootInstance.children
    # Set the values for x, y, and z
    x = float(inputVals['entry00'].get()) + float(inputVals['entry01'].get()) - float(inputVals['entry02'].get())
    y = float(inputVals['entry10'].get()) + float(inputVals['entry11'].get()) - float(inputVals['entry12'].get())
    z = float(inputVals['entry20'].get()) + float(inputVals['entry21'].get()) - float(inputVals['entry22'].get())
    # Get our output label string variables
    outputList = output
    # Process the x, y, and z variables
    num = x + y - z
    # Set our x, y, and z variables to a list
    list = [x, y, z]
    # Iterate over our list and outputList variables in a zipped fashion
    for i, j in zip(list, outputList):
        fin = 2000*i*num
        # Set the value of the output equal to our computed value
        j.set(str(fin))
    # Update our root instance
    rootInstance.update_idletasks()

# Define our main method
def main():
    # Create our root tkinter instance
    root = tk.Tk()
    # Specify size of window
    root.geometry("650x200")
    # Create our input fields
    rows = []
    for i in range(3):
        cols = []
        for j in range(3):
            e = tk.Entry(root, relief=tk.RIDGE, name=('entry' + str(i) + str(j)))
            e.grid(row=i, column=j, sticky=tk.NSEW)
            e.insert(tk.END, '%d.%d' % (i, j))
            cols.append(e)
        rows.append(cols)
    # Add a section for our output below:
    outputText = tk.Label(root, text = "Output", font="Arial 11 bold").grid(row=4, column=0)
    out1 = tk.StringVar()
    out1.set("-")
    out2 = tk.StringVar()
    out2.set("-")
    out3 = tk.StringVar()
    out3.set("-")
    output1 = tk.Label(root, textvariable = out1, name='output1').grid(row=5, column=0)
    output2 = tk.Label(root, textvariable = out2, name='output2').grid(row=5, column=1)
    output3 = tk.Label(root, textvariable = out3, name='output3').grid(row=5, column=2)
    # Add a lambda function to our button command below, so it only executes when we click the button
    button_calc = tk.Button(root, text='Calculate', command= lambda: onPress(root, [out1, out2, out3])).grid(row=3, column=0)
    root.update()
    # Call the main loop of our tkinter instance
    root.mainloop()

# Execute our "main" function below
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**That should yield some output like below:**

[image: tkinter screenshot]

For reference, the thread below talk more about using tkinter with text variables:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-setting-and-retrieving-values-of-tkinter-variable/

Comment: @Thando Sure thing - Feel free to upvote the answer, if you feel that the code above answers the question